Woocommerce subscriptions apply discount to actual price instead of signup fee
Since Woocommerce Subscriptions does not offer a paid trial I'm charging a 1$ signup fee to my subscription in order to create a 1$ 7 day trial.
My issue is however that once a discount code gets applied in checkout, this discount gets applied to the 1$ trial, and not to the actual subscription price (the monthly price).
Is there a hook/function I can use to change this behaviour?

I know enough Woocommerce to be able to help out, but i never used Woocommerce Subscriptions and your description is too cryptic to me. Isn’t it an option to create a normal subscription of 1 dollar and call it “trial”, then find a way to stop the subscription after 7 days?
